# Struggling to iterate over a "populated" model on the client side

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loops, express, ejs

I'm looking to build a bootstrap table on the client side that shows which `events` a `guest` has attended. I've been working on this for a couple days and had initially had most of the `guest` data live in the `event` model (guests are 1:many with events) and referenced the `guest._id`.

This made creating a clean object challenging so I moved `giveaway_interest` and `winner` over to the `guest` model and referenced the `event`. This makes those two fields easier to display in my table but I still am struggling to pull in `event_name` and `event_start`.

**Fields**

- Event name (from `event` model)
- Event start (from `event model)
- Giveaway interest (from `guest` model)
- Winner status (from `guest` model)

**Context**
Right now I'm writing both `giveaway_interest` and `winner` to *both* models. I don't want to do this with `event_name` because that can be changed and then the guest model would be out of date.

**Question**
How do I rewrite this to display the four fields listed above on my `show.ejs` page?

**Controller function**
path: controllers/guests.js

```
module.exports.showGuest = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
        const guest = await Guest.findById(req.params.id).populate('events');
        const events = guest.events.map(guestEvent => guestEvent.event);
        console.log("guest ", guest);         // object below
        console.log("events ", events);       // [ undefined, undefined ]
        res.render('guests/show', { guest, moment, events });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
}
```

The view gets tripped up at the row `<%= guestEvent.event._id %>` and renders error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')` from the first column of the table.

```
<h3>Attended Events</h3>
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <th>Giveaway Interest</th>
        <th>Winner</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% guest.events.forEach(guestEvent => { %>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="/events/<%= guestEvent.event._id %>"><%= guestEvent.event.event_name %></a></td>.  // line causing error
          <td><%= moment(guestEvent.event.event_start).format('MM/DD/YY') %></td>
          <td><%= guestEvent.giveaway_interest %></td>
          <td><%= guestEvent.winner ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
        </tr>
      <% }) %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Guest model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const guestSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    dateAdded: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    events: [
        {
            event: {
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: 'Event',
              required: false
            },
            giveaway_interest: {
                type: String,
                default: null
              },
              redeemed: {
                type: String,
                default: "No",
                date: {
                  type: Date,
                  default: Date.now,
                },
                updatedBy: String,
                comments: String,
              },
              notified: {
                type: String,
                default: "No",
                date: {
                  type: Date,
                  default: Date.now,
                },
              },
              winner: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: null
              },
        },    
    ],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

**Event model**

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  qr_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Enter a name for your QR code'],
  },
  event_name: String,
  address: String,
  winner_index: [
    {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  ],
  geometry: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
    }
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  qr: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Qr'
  },
  guests: [
    {
      guest: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Guest',
        required: false
      },
      // this is written to both models at the moment
      giveaway_interest: {
        type: String,
      },
      redeemed: {
        type: String,
        default: "No",
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
        updatedBy: String,
        comments: String,
      },
      notified: {
        type: String,
        default: "No",
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
      },
      winner: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: null
      },
    },
  ],
  event_start: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date & time of event start required']
  },
  event_end: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date & time of event end required']
  },
  winners: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Quantity required']
  },
}, opts);
```

**Guest object from controller console.log**

```
guest  {
  _id: new ObjectId("xxxxxxx3571"),
  email: 'tom@company.io',
  firstName: 'Tom',
  dateAdded: 2023-05-25T00:48:53.573Z,
  events: [
    {
      giveaway_interest: 'alumni-events',
      redeemed: 'No',
      notified: 'No',
      winner: true,
      _id: new ObjectId("xxxxxxx3924")
    },
    {
      giveaway_interest: 'merchandise',
      redeemed: 'No',
      notified: 'No',
      winner: false,
      _id: new ObjectId("xxxxxxx42e8")
    }
  ],
  user: new ObjectId("xxxxxxxf3fb"),
  __v: 1
}
```